# Changing Text With After The Click of Button Using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I was trying to figure out how I can display "it's red's turn", than after red click's it will display it's blue's turn and vice versa.

This is what I tried doing so far:

```
    if redPlayer == True:
        RedTurn = Label(display,
                        text="It's Red Player's turn",
                        fg='red',
                        font="Times 32",
                        width=30,
                        height=2)
        RedTurn.pack()

    if bluePlayer == True:
        BlueTurn = Label(display,
                        text="It's Blue Player's turn",
                        fg='blue',
                        font="Times 32",
                        width=30,
                        height=2)
        BlueTurn.pack()
```

Comment: Why don't you create 1 label then use `<tkinter.Label>.config(text=<new text>)`

Comment: Where could I implement this in my code?

Comment: When you are setting up your window just add `label = Label(display, ...)` and `label.pack()` then in that function you can just call `label.config(text=<new text>)`

Comment: I can't give you a proper answer unless you show me the code that creates the `display` and how that function is called.

Answer (score 1):

Change a label's text with `config(text=progress)`:

```
from tkinter import *

def clicked():
    l.config(text='changed!')
    
    
root = Tk()

l = Label(text='Click button to change text')
b = Button(text='click', command=clicked)

l.pack()
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

> how I can display "it's red's turn", than after red click's it will
> display it's blue's turn and vice versa.

Create `your_turn()` function.

- Just use one `Label` widget instead of a duplicated `Label` widget.
- Add `your_turn_label.configure` in `your_turn()` function.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk


redPlayer: bool = True
bluePlayer: bool = False

def your_turn():
    global redPlayer, bluePlayer
    if redPlayer:
        your_turn_label.configure(text="It's Red Player's turn")
        your_turn_label.configure(fg='red')
        redPlayer = not redPlayer
    else:                 
        your_turn_label.configure(text="It's Blue Player's turn")
        your_turn_label.configure(fg='blue')
        redPlayer = not redPlayer   
                    
           
root = tk.Tk()

your_turn_label = tk.Label(text='Click button to change text', font="Times 32", width=30,height=2, )
your_turn_button = tk.Button(text='click', command=your_turn)

your_turn_label.pack()
your_turn_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]